# Improperly formatted JSON, no idea what is incorrect

Tags: json, formatting

I have a JSON string here.  In Python, whenever I `json.loads(string)`, I get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 21 (char 20)`.  However, I am completely lost on why it is an improperly formatted JSON.  I have tried adding `r` infront of the string but with no avail.

JSON String:

`string = '{"alarm_flood": "[{"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "1", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}, {"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "0", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}]", "flood_status": "[{"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "1", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}, {"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "0", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}]"}'`

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to show a solution/answer. That's what *answers* are for. I rolled back this edit (plus it's already covered in someone's answer to you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some extra quotation marks. Here is the corrected version:

```
string = '{"alarm_flood": [{"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "1", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}, {"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "0", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}], "flood_status": [{"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "1", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}, {"Date_Time": "01-12-2009 12:18:42", "flood_status": "0", "FloodIndex": "0", "Plant_Area": "AREA 1"}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

you have some extra double quotes, you can remove them using replace

```
string = string.replace('"[', '[').replace(']"', ']');
```